# How to upgrade/update makeinfo/texinfo from version 4.8 to 4.13 on macOSX terminal command line?

Tags: macos, upgrade, updates, texinfo

I have makeinfo 4.8 already installed. Command line typing `$ makeinfo --version` returns `makeinfo (GNU texinfo) 4.8`.

I'd like to update the version to the latest 4.13. I've found relevant info [here](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/mailarchive/commits/2011-05/msg00004.html) and [here](http://gitweb.dragonflybsd.org/dragonfly.git/commitdiff/faea168fe416cfd1c5acb80db5108af0310b7ae9). I'm new to command line/bash/git... Please help me out, much appreciated!

Comment: There's another [link](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/) that's relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at this issue, you shouldn't need dragonfly (or git commands):

```
configure: error: You do not seem to have makeinfo >= 4.13, and your
source tree does not seem to have pre-built manuals in the 'info' directory.
Either install a suitable version of makeinfo, or re-run configure
with the '--without-makeinfo' option to build without the manuals.
```

> I've tried `brew install texinfo` and then `brew ln texinfo --force` and now `makeinfo --version` shows `texi2any (GNU texinfo) 6.3`

Note, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379909/how-to-upgrade-update-makeinfo-texinfo-from-version-4-8-to-4-13-on-macosx-termin/44382617#comment77805750_44382617) by [jmq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551899/jmq)::

> If you use `brew` to install, make sure you have `/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin` in your path, and it is before `/usr/bin`.
>   Version 4.8 of this tool on the Mac (10.12.6) is located in `/usr/bin/makeinfo`.
>   If this path is in front of the latter, then it will not find the latest version installed by `brew`.

Comment: If you use brew to install make sure you have `/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin
` in your path and it is before `/usr/bin`.  Version 4.8 of this tool on the Mac (10.12.6) is located in `/usr/bin/makeinfo`.  If this path is in front of the latter, then it will not find the latest version installed by brew.

Comment: @jmq Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got hit with this while trying to build GnuPG from sources on macOS: makeinfo: unrecognized option `--css-ref=/share/site.css'

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky OK. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @VonC yup, with the `brew install` and `export MAKEINFO=/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/makeinfo` before calling GnuPG's `./configure`

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky That should work, indeed. Well done.